# Sending XML from Java to MSMQ - bodyType from VT_EMPTY to VT_BSTR

Tags: java, xml, msmq

We work on a Java (Java EE) application, and we generate XML files in order to send them to a remote .NET application with MSMQ reading on their side.
The XML file is generated by JDom, like so :

```
// add elements...

Document doc = new Document(root);      
String XmlData = new XMLOutputter(Format.getPrettyFormat().setOmitEncoding(true)).outputString(doc);

try {
        SendFile( XmlData, "title" , "path");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MessageQueueException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Then we use this function, using the [MsmqJava library](http://msmqjava.codeplex.com/) to send the file :

```
private void SendFile(String data, String title, String outputPath) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, MessageQueueException{
    String qname="name_of_the_queue";
    String fullname= "server_path" + qname;
    String body = data;
    String label = title;
    String correlationId= "L:none";

    try {
        Queue queue= new Queue(fullname);
        Message msg= new Message(body, label, correlationId);
        queue.send(msg);
            } catch (MessageQueueException ex1) {
           System.out.println("Put failure: " + ex1.toString());
       }
}
```

They correctly receive the file, but they told us that the bodyType was set to "VT_EMPTY" while they wanted "VT_BSTR", and we haven't find a clue about how to fix this. If you know another lib who does the job, or a workaround to this one, we can change with no problem.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the documentation for the library you use, it is not possible using that library.

Jmsmqqueue also doesn't provide the functionality you need.

It seems sun also had an adapter: https://wikis.oracle.com/display/JavaCAPS/Sun+Adapter+for+MSMQ

Comment: It seems that this adapter is included in the Java CAPS thing, do you know where can i found a free version of this ? This seems like a ghost lib

Comment: If I understand the docs correctly, it is now part of the java CAPS suite. No idea as to how or where to download that. (it seems it is integrated into several other products)